# Create a VPN network between a live server and private networks

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn

I have a VPS (Cent OS 6) on a live IP. I have several other machines (All linux, mostly Cent OS  6 and a few Android devices) sitting behind  NATted ADSL Routers on several sites.

I need to create a VPN between them, so that any device can ping or ssh into other devices participating in the VPN. Live Server can act as the host. Security is important.

I fairly comfortable with Linux CLI, but I don't know where to start for this project.

My questions is, What are the steps that I need to do to achieve the above setup?

Answer (score 3):

The whole setup is too long to be described here, also there are multiple ways how you might want to configure it, so to provide an overview:

- You need to setup OpenVPN server. I would advice to do it on a VPS with external IP.
- Setup OpenVPN clients on other servers and android devices to connect to your OpenVPN server.

You can find quick setup/proof-of-concept guide on OpenVPN site: http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/78-static-key-mini-howto.html

CentOS specific guides:

- http://www.servermom.org/how-to-build-openvpn-server-on-centos-6-x/732/
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-setup-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-6